# HTML element not selecting in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

So I have an HTML excerpt from a webpage as follows:

```
<li class="PaEvOc tv5olb wbTnP gws-horizon-textlists__li-ed">
  //random div/element stuff inside here
</li>
<li class ="PaEvOc tv5olb gws-horizon-textlists__li-ed">
  //random div/element stuff inside here as well
</li>
```

Not sure how to properly copy HTML but if you look at "events near *location*" on Google Chrome, I'm looking at these and trying to scrape the data from them:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fv4a4.png

To start, I'm just trying to figure out how to properly select these elements in Puppeteer:

```
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ args: [
  '--no-sandbox'
  ]});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  page.once('load', () => console.log('Page loaded!'));
  await page.goto('https://www.google.com/search?q=events+near+poughkeepsie+today&client=safari&rls=en&uact=5&ibp=htl;events&rciv=evn&sa=X&fpstate=tldetail');
  console.log('Hit wait for selector')
  const test = await page.waitForSelector(".PaEvOc");
  console.log('finished waiting for selector');
  const seeMoreEventsButton = await page.$(".PaEvOc");

  console.log('seeMoreEventsButton is ' + seeMoreEventsButton);
  console.log('test is ' + test);
})();
```

What exactly is the problem here? Any and all help much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: run it with headless: false so you can see what's happening.

Comment: @pguardiario Running it on Heroku, which doesn't support headless: false

Comment: So you're not testing it locally first?

Comment: Ohhhhhh I should do that, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest reading this: https://intoli.com/blog/not-possible-to-block-chrome-headless/

Basically, websites are detecting that you are scraping, but you can work around it.

Here is what I did to make your console logs print something useful

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {                                                    
  const preparePageForTests = async (page) => {
    const userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64)' +           
      'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.39 Safari/537.36';
    await page.setUserAgent(userAgent);
  }   

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ args: [                
  '--no-sandbox'                                                  
  ]});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await preparePageForTests(page);
      
  page.once('load', () => console.log('Page loaded!'));           
  await page.goto('https://www.google.com/search?q=events+near+poughkeepsie+today&client=safari&rls=en&uact=5&ibp=htl;events&rciv=evn&sa=X&fpstate=tldetail');                                        
  
  console.log('Hit wait for selector')
  const test = await page.waitForSelector(".PaEvOc");
    
  console.log('finished waiting for selector');                   
  const seeMoreEventsButton = await page.$(".PaEvOc");            
    
  console.log('seeMoreEventsButton is ' + seeMoreEventsButton);   
  console.log('test is ' + test);                                 
})();
```

Comment: Very very helpful article--so should I implement all the test "passes"? Will the passes become obsolete in the future (for example will I have to change userAgent to something else in the future? What do you recommend?

Comment: I would do the minimal to make it work. Different sites will perform different checks, and your concerns about them changing are valid. IMO the best you can do is monitor it so that if it starts failing, you can react quickly to fix by employing some of the other strategies listed on that page.

Comment: And are those tests that different sites run the only ones? Or are those the main ones? Is there a way to know which test specifically is causing the rejection?

Comment: I think it's a bit of a cat & mouse game. I did this userAgent trick to get puppeteer to talk to costco.com and haven't had any issues since. Honestly, I don't have a lot of experience with this, which is why I was happy to find this article.

Comment: Fair enough, thank you for all of your help!